# Why when I use width: 100%, my wrapper box doesn't fit all the screen?

Tags: css

Why when I use width: 100%, my wrapper box doesn't fit all the screen but when I use width:100vw it fits all the screen. "width=device-width" is used on my page. The width for the page is min-width: 1400px;

thank all of you for your help

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

width:100%
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmUH9.jpg
width:100vw
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/39kpm.jpg

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px){

    body{
        min-width: 1400px;
    }    


    .wrapper{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100%;
        background:  var(--DarkCyan);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your wrapper class is taking "100%" of its parent container, the body. You set the body to have a min-width of 1400px, which means it won't expand past 1400px unless its contents exceed that width. Therefore, the wrapper child class will only take up as much as its parent defines it to, in this case only 1400px.

Percentage values (100%) depends on the parent container's value, while viewport values (100vw) are isolated from other elements and render based on the screen's view port